# How to find a component inside another component in jest?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I want to find a component inside another component in Jest. After finding the component The length should be `1` but I am getting `0` length.

Test cases code is as follows -

```
beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = enzyme.mount(
                <Rest
                    onApplyClick={mockOnApplyClick}
                    translateFn={mockTranslateFn}
                    someData={mockSomeData}
                />
            );
});
```

and then we have test case -

```
it('Test case', () => {
        let Button= wrapper.find(Button);
        Button.simulate('click');
        expect(wrapper.find(StyledPopover).prop('open')).toBe(true);
        act(() => {
            let newWrapper = wrapper
                .find(<NewComponent {...props} myData={mockMyData[1]} />)
                expect(newWrapper.length).toBe(1);
                console.log(newWrapper.length, "newWrapper.length")
    });
});
```

I am getting `0` length in `console.log(newWrapper.length)` But if we are passing `let newWrapper = wrapper.find(NewComponent)` Then I am getting length `1`. So how to resolve this issue as I want to pass props to `NewComponent` so that I can find some other elements inside `NewComponent`.

Comment: @hurricane isn't it the other way around, you use shallow when you *don't* want to render child components?

Comment: You can try `wrapper.find(NewComponent).setProps({props1: value})`

Comment: @UKS it is saying  `ReactWrapper::setProps() can only be called on the root.` When I am setting props

Comment: Ok Can you add your Rest Component ?

Comment: I did the change  - `act(() => {
   let newWrapper = wrapper.setProps({ children: <NewComponent {...props} myData={mockMyData[1]}  /> });
    expect(newWrapper.length).toBe(1);
    newWrapper
        .find(RadioButton)
        .first()
        .props()
        .onChange('hello', {target:{id:'hello' , isChecked: false} });` Now it is saying TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

Comment: Include your `Rest` Component in the question. I will try running it in my local machine

Comment: @UKS So big code. Not possible to paste it here. Can we discuss somewhere else ?

Comment: @UKS As I told you it is saying undefined ID. This is my function code to get target ID - `const onChangeID=(event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
  setRadioData(event.target.id);
 }`